# Save JavaScript Variable to Django Database -

Tags: javascript, database, variables, quill

I'm a beginner and I've started making a website. I need to take the delta created from the quill text editor and save it in the database. The variable is in the script tag as HTML. I need that variable extracted to views.py and I think I will be able to do the rest... hopefully. Any tip I really need guidance on this. There might even be a better way that I am not seeing.

This is my javascript in my HTML file:

```
<script>

  var toolbarOptions = [
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    ['bold', 'italic'],
    [{ 'align': [] }],
    [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],
    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
    [ 'image', 'link', 'video' ],
    ['blockquote'],
    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],
    ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button

  ]
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
      toolbar: toolbarOptions
    },
    theme: 'snow'
  });
  function logHtmlContent() {
    console.log(quill.root.innerHTML);
  }
quill.on('text-change', update);
var container = document.querySelector('#delta-container');
update();

function update(delta) {
  var contents = quill.getContents();
  console.log('contents', contents);
  var html = "contents = " + JSON.stringify(contents, null, 2);
  if (delta) {
    console.log('change', delta)
    html = "change = " + JSON.stringify(delta, null, 2) + "\n\n" + html;
  }
  container.innerHTML = HTML;
  hljs.highlightBlock(container);
}
</script>
```

This is the views I'm trying to be able to access the variable in.

```
def template(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = TextForm(request.POST or None)
    form.save()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {})

else:
    return render(request, 'template.html', {})
```